# Using and (&&) and or (||) together in the same condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how to combine and (&&) with or (||) in JavaScript.

I want to check if either both a and b equal 1 or if both c and d equal 1.

I've tried this:

```
if (a == 1 && b == 1 || c == 1 && d == 1)
{
    //Do something
}
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I write this condition correctly?

Comment: if ((a == 1 && b == 1) || (c == 1 && d == 1)) {}

Comment: Do you mean (a and b equals 1) or (c and d=1) ? OR : 
(a=1 and (b or c=1) and d=1) ? it is not clear !

Comment: this is the case for most languages btw, not just javascript

Comment: Your snippet works just fine, the problem is somewhere else. Post more code.

Comment: When you say you want to check "either", are you talking about an exclusive OR?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&&` [precedes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) `||`. `==` precedes both of them.

From your minimal example I don't see, why it doesn't achieve your desired effect. What kind of value types do a–d have? JavaScript might have some non-obvious [type coercion](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/) going on. Maybe try comparing with `===` or convert to numbers explicitly.

*Side note:* many lint tools for C-like languages recommend to throw in parentheses for readability when mixing logical operators.

Answer (score 5):

[Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) can be overridden by placing the expression between parenthesis.

```
 if ((+a == 1 && +b == 1) || (+c == 1 && +d == 1)) // Use brackets to group them
 {
   // your code
 }
```

This will prevent you from such cases like `if(0&&0 || 1&&1)` .

Comment: The parentheses you've added are redundant because && already has a higher precedence than || so JS already evaluates the expression in the way you've grouped it.

Comment: `0&&0||1&&1` evaluates to `1`, which just proves my point. But `false && false || true && true` is a better example (and it returns `true`). Adding parentheses doesn't make any difference either way.

Answer (score 2):

Well now that I've finished telling everybody else (except David) why their answers are wrong, let me give them the same chance to hassle me.

Your existing code as shown should already do what you *seem* to be describing. But is it possible that when you say:

> *"I want to check if either both a and b equals 1 or if both c and d equals 1."*

...your use of the word "either" mean that you want to check if one *and only one* of the following conditions is true:

- both a and b are 1, but c and d are not both 1
- both c and d are 1, but a and b are not both 1

That is, you want one pair of variables to be 1, but you don't want all four variables to be 1 at the same time?

If so, that is an *exclusive OR* operation, which in JS is the [`^` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators#.5E_%28Bitwise_XOR%29):

```
if ((a == 1 && b == 1) ^ (c == 1 && d == 1)) {
```

Note that unlike with a logical OR `||` operator, you have to add parentheses around the AND `&&` parts of the expression because `^` has higher precendence. (`^` is actually a bitwise operator, but it will work for you here since the operands you'd be using with it are all booleans.)

Comment: For boolean values, you might just use the `!==` XOR operator instead of that bitwise thing which will convert everything to numbers…

Comment: @Bergi - I don't know what you mean by "!== XOR operator". You can rewrite XOR as a combination of AND and OR, but the result is longer since you have to repeat the operands (as in my dot points, above). And in this case a bitwise XOR works fine since its operands are booleans so they're OK converted to numbers - the result of the whole expression will be `0` or `1`, which is fine for use in an `if()` test where you just need falsey or truthy.

Comment: Check the truth table. "not equal" *is* "exclusive or" - so why use the bitwise thing it there's already an operator for XOR?

Comment: @Bergi - Oh right, I understand now, thanks. To my way of thinking `^` is clearer because I explicitly read it as "XOR", whereas I'm too used to using "not equal" for non boolean logic situations. (So you might ask "Don't you use `^` for bitwise operations?" In practice, no, I've never needed to do that in JavaScript, just in other languages and even then not often.) Of course I'm just guessing here that XOR is even what the OP is trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

place some extra brackets to differentiate the and n or conditions

```
if ((a == 1 && b == 1) || (c == 1 && d == 1))
```

Comment: You don't need to add brackets, because `&&` already has higher precedence than `||`.

Comment: Who remembers all the operators' precedence and associativity? It's always a good practice to use ( parens ) to separate binary operators and make the intention of the author clear. Better safe than sorry.